# COM-object in service application cannot be accessed

Tags: delphi, service, com

I`m developing a service application with COM-object in it (OPC Data Access 2.05 server). I have this code for registration my object, which is executed after installation:

```
procedure TOPCService.ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
var
  lcHResult:     HRESULT;
  lcCLSIDString: String;
begin
  ComServer.UpdateRegistry(True);

  lcCLSIDString:=GUIDToString(CLASS_TestOPCServerDA2);

  ComObj.CreateRegKey('AppID\'+lcCLSIDString,                             '',      'Test OPC Server DA2');
  ComObj.CreateRegKey('AppID\'+Application.ExeName,                       'AppId', lcCLSIDString);
  ComObj.CreateRegKey('CLSID\'+lcCLSIDString+'\VersionIndependentProgID', '',      C_TEST_OPC_DA2_SERVER_NAME);

  <opc server registration stuff>

  RegisterAsService(lcCLSIDString, Name);
end;
```

The service and COM-object are properly register in the system, so i can see my service in SCM and COM-object in OLE/COM object viewer (and also in OPC clients).
The COM-object itself looks like this:

```
type
  TTestOPCServerDA2 = class(TAutoObject, ITestOPCServerDA2, IConnectionPointContainer, IOPCServer, IOPCCommon, IOPCItemProperties, IOPCBrowseServerAddressSpace)
```

with its factory registration code:

```
initialization
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TTestOPCServerDA2, Class_TestOPCServerDA2, ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
```

The problem is when i try to CoCreateInstance(CLASS_TestOPCServerDA2) (via CreateComObject wrapper), i got freeze for 120 second and 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE) error after. In SCM and Task Manager i see my service is started when COM-object is requested, but nothing else happens. If i stop the serivce and try againg, service would be started again, so i assume Windows knows about my COM-object, its executable and the fact that executable is a service.
I also tried to change user which my service is running under (to the same with the invoking application), but that did not help.
What am i missing?

**Edit 1.** I created new project and got rid of OPC (just left COM support) to isolate the problem, so now my class is looks like this:

```
type
  TTestCOMServer = class(TAutoObject, ITestCOMServer)
  end;
...
initialization
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TTestCOMServer, Class_TestCOMServer, ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
```

And the service thread:

```
procedure TCOMService.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while (not Terminated) do
  begin
    ReportStatus;
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);

    Sleep(25);
  end;
```

The problem persists: when i try to CoCreateInstance, nothing happens and calling app hangs for 120 seconds.
**But!** If i make 1 change: uncommenting *Application.DelayInitialize := True;* in dpr, COM-object gets created well and calling app freezes no longer! Is it the service execute thread that (not service main thread) processes COM-requests?

**Edit 2.** It seems that only DelayInititalization is requred. ProcessRequests can be called with *False* argument and sleep can have its place - i must have not properly rebuilded my project.
So, i think the answer to my question is to uncomment *Application.DelayInitialize := True;* in DPR-file. Delphi autogenerate text about that, but it mentions only Windows 2003 Server condition and my OS is Windows 10.

Comment: CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE means "Server execution failed" which means your COM server failed to register object in time or failed to answers interface called, etc. There can be many causes. Difficult to say more w/o full reproducing code.

Comment: Did you try with a regular executable (not a service)?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine as regular application. I edited my post with new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case (Delphi XE3 under Windows 10 Pro) i had to uncomment

```
Application.DelayInitialize := True;
```

in DPR. After this change, COM-object is created properly.